# how to import cucumber eclipse plugin manually?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I couldn't install cucumber eclipse plugin from "http://cucumber.github.com/cucumber-eclipse/update-site
" from Help--> Install New software because of firewall restriction.

Can anyone provide the jars for recent cucumber eclipse plugin and provide the steps to manually add them to eclipse please ?

Comment: Installation of Cucumber plugin for Eclipse and Maven dependencies to use Cucumber with your project are two completely different things. I am confused as to why you checked the provided answer as "best answer" when it doesn't address the installation of the plugin?

The plugin provides an editor for Cucumber files that gives you the ability to see which step definitions are implemented and which ones are not (among other things). Adding Cucumber to Maven only helps you using Cucumber classes and annotations with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website might be helpful for you:

http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/download-cucumber-jvm-eclipse/

There are 3 options available:

**1.** Download Cucumber Jars from Online Maven Repository

**2.** Download Cucumber Jars from oss.sonatype.org

**3.** Download Cucumber Jars from Maven dependencies

All of them are detailed on the website.

Hope it helps!